# Why do some anti-reflective (or anti-glare) lenses use layers of materials with alternately very high and very low refractive indices?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, lenses, optical-materials

Some specials lenses like this (or coatings on them) try to minimize the refractive index, or the change thereof, or at least make the change very gradual.

But others apparently do the exact opposite, alternating layers of materials with very high and very low refractive indices....

Why?

Comment: Could you elaborate on where you can find impedance matching (matching refractive index) anti-reflective coatings?

Comment: I was going to write an answer, but would this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548740/optical-impedance-matching/548754#548754

Answer (score 1):

I will add to the answer given in the comments.

In a way it does not matter which materials you use for anti-reflective (AR) coating. Because what you do is use the interference between the reflection of a layer and a deeper layer, tuned via the thickness of the underlying layer. If the difference in phase is $\pi$ then you have destructive interference on the reflection which means that the light must be transmitted.

As the amount of reflected light is a function of the difference between the refractive indices, using highly mismatched indices means you have a higher reflectivity value and so you will need fewer layers to achieve a certain target transmission/reflectivity for a certain light frequency. This of course has its caveats like how broadband the coating can be, manufacturing tolerances etc. So in the end is all about engineering of the coatings.

But if you really want to go deeper, high performance coatings sometimes start with a small region for index matching with air (personal opinion: I don't really see it, either way, of course that the point is for easing the mismatch, but its still not possible to match air/vacuum to any solid transparent dielectric (at least from visible to near-infrared), in a professional setting it's all fine as we all understand each other, but it's slightly misleading in a broader sense) and then high-low stacks. But the part that really does the heavy lifting are the high-low stacks and how they are arranged for what the optic should do, be either anti-reflective, highly-reflective, low dispersion, broadband, target negative/positive dispersion etc. Nonetheless, if there is someone from the coating industry that would like to elaborate further, then you might have a better answer.